# parse.com javascript sdk security

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform

I want to use the parse javascript sdk because of it's features and simple implementation, It is awesome, but I cannot wrap my head around it's openiness to anyone who wants to access your data, the security keys are available in the sourcecode and this means anyone can set up objects and query them.

In my mind, this means one person can use another persons account and the owner of the account has to pay for the requests that are used by a random person(until the breach is discovered). The number of requests used is parse's business model, so this is worrying.

Am I missing something?

Comment: 1. it is build primary for creating apps. nobody ask you to use in web browser.
2. you are free to proxy the request using your own server if you intend to use in browser.

Comment: You can create class level permission and roles. then unregistered users can't query. Also there is ACL (access control list) for every row.